# Replace each ocurrence of a link with its specific href object (map link -> a href=link) in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, react-native

I need to replace

```
 "wjjghwkjghwkjgh https://www.google.com jhgkwjhgkwhgk https://youtube.com"
```

with

```
 "wjjghwkjghwkjgh <a href='https://www.google.com'>https://www.google.com</a> jhgkwjhgkwhgk <a href='https://youtube.com'>https://youtube.com</a>";
```

I already did a draft https://jsbin.com/kosogijudo/1/edit?js,console with the regex link and a sample message to help

I don't know how to do it, since if I create a loop it'll modify the first correctly, but in the second iteration it'll modify again inside the  tag.

I think there is a way to specify a mapping function that takes `link` and outputs `<a href="link">link</a>`

By the way, all of this because I need to use https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview on react native to display links inside text views. If there is a modern way to do it in React Native itself it'll be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `replace` method by passing a replacer function as the second parameter. [More details on MDN about the parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

The replacer function is called for each match and it's return value is used to replace the original match in the string. Here is a sample, hope it helps

```js
var regexp = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;

var test = 'wjjghwkjghwkjgh https://www.google.com jhgkwjhgkwhgk https://youtube.com'

var replaced = test.replace(regexp,function(match){
 return `<a href="${match}">${match}</a>`;
})

console.log(replaced); //wjjghwkjghwkjgh <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a> jhgkwjhgkwhgk <a href="https://youtube.com">https://youtube.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out

```
var string = "wjjghwkjghwkjgh https://www.google.com jhgkwjhgkwhgk https://youtube.com";
string.split(' ');
var answer = string.map(m => (m.includes('https') && [`<a href=${m}>${m}</a>`].join(m)) || m).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not wrapping the matched string in a `<a>` tag
2. You're not capturing the URL (with a Regex capture group) so $1 is wrong
3. Add the `g` flag after your regex (global), so it processes more than one URL in the string

```js
const linkRegex = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g

let message = "wjjghwkjghwkjgh https://www.google.com jhgkwjhgkwhgk https://youtube.com";

message = message.replace(linkRegex, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>") // Wrap in <a>

console.log(message)
```